# How to setup and run ionic app and node express api within one application?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I have two separate applications one is the ionic app and other is node express api app. Is it possible to merge both in one application? Like for example when i enter npm run start it should run ionic serve and node index js both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically after you finish developing your frontend you "build" it. This minifies and optimizes frontend files. For ionic: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/build

This creates a folder(the default name can be "dist" or "build" etc). You put this folder in your backend folder, then serve it statically. For static serving check out https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html.

This way you deploy only backend, and it works. You can make api endpoint routes start with "/api" and "/" routes can be for frontend's static serving.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to do that for development purposes only, you can use `concurrently` command https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

`npm install -g concurrently`

After installation, add this line to `package.json` script
`"start": "concurrently \"command1 arg\" \"command2 arg\""`

In command1: add ionic start command, like: `ionic start`
In command2: add node start command, like: `nodemon server.js`

Comment: Thanks! How can i achieve the same for production?

Comment: In production you will need to build each application, using `ionic build` and `npm run build` for node depending on your module bundler (babel, webpack, typescript) setup for example, and deploy those files to the server you want to use, or to the store in ionic case

Comment: I got it from a build perspective, but the src folder remains the same for both the applications? or should it be separate? i believe keeping it separate but within the same app is more robust in terms of maintainance.

Comment: Right, each app should be completely separated, as if two developers are working in each one separately.
As you said, it's better for maintenance and in production each app will be published to a separate place so it better this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will give it a try right away.