# NodeJS Application to publish as APP and Backend service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

NodeJs Application to publish as APP and Backend service.

I am using NodeJs application with the ionic app as a web application in the same project

I am running this application locally by running these commands 1) node server.js and 2) npm run watch.

So now I have to publish this application to Azure Static app service or App services.

Which is the best way to publish the application?

Should I include these steps for the static app service yml file?

app_location: "/" # App source code path
api_location: "/api" # Api source code path - optional
api_build_command: 'node server.js'
app_build_command: 'npm run build'
output_location: "dist" # Built app content directory - optional

Which place I should publish API and app?

I am adding a project architecture app is having my services source having my web application
[image: I am adding a project architecture app is having my services source having my web application]

Api's architecture

[image: Api's architecture image]

Answer (score 0):

***You can deploy your NodeJs Application with Ionic App as web application to Azure App Service through VScode, CLI and portal.***

Create an Azure App Service by selecting *NodeJs* as runtime stack and *code* as publish mode:
[image]

- ***Create NodeJs Application and Ionic Application***.
- Run `ionic build`, it will create `www` folder, copy this folder to public folder of your backend application,

[image]
then use it statistically by including

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

or

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

This way you can directly deploy your backend application.

**Deployment:**

- Open your application in vscode.
- Signin to Azure in vscode to deploy your application Azure App service. [ctrl+shift+p(Command Palette)-> Signin to Azure->select subscription]:

[image]

Select Azure in left panel-> Go to Workspace->click on deploy to web app-> Select your project.
[image]

Select resource(your app service) and click on deploy.
[image]

Once deployment succeeds, it will be seen as below:
[image]

Go to App Service->Advanced Tools-> Click on Go-> It will be redirected to your kudu site which contains all the deployed files in Debug Console->cmd->site->www folder: ***verify if all the required files are deployed.***

[image]

As @[srknzl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67043206/19991670) mentioned, Make your API endpoint routes start with "/api" and "/" for frontend's static serving.

To modify the virtual path as per your requirement -> Go to configuration->path mappings->
[image]